# C# error: "Can't convert "int " into "System.Func<Creature, int>""

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please help me with this question. I'm coding come ability system in Unity3D 2019.4.1 (if you might want to know) and have had created "Roller" class for some random numbers. There is

```
public static Func<Creature, int> OnNumberRolled;
```

in "Roller" class. Some of abilities in my game must know about these random numbers and when they are rolled, they invoke some mess.
Here is an ability class:

```
public class ListenerEffect : Effect
{
   public int OnRolledOne(Creature creature)
   {
      ...
   }

   public override void CastEffect(ITargetable caster, ITargetable target)
   {
       Creature localCasterCreature = caster as Creature;
       Roller.OnNumberRolled += OnRolledOne(localTargetCreature);
   }
}
```

At this moment

```
Roller.OnNumberRolled += OnRolledOne(localTargetCreature);
```

error occurs. It says that it can't convert "int" into "System.Func<Creature, int>". Both classes are using System. What should I do?

Comment: Please read up on events in C# and how they work.

Comment: In your example ```OnRolledOne(localTargetCreature)``` will execute the function and return and int. That's why you can't assign it to OnNumberRolled that expects a Func<Create,int>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the name of the function. Otherwise, you are calling the function and are using the returned value.

```cs
    Roller.OnNumberRolled += OnRolledOne;
```

If you add several handlers, keep in mind that the return values will be lost (but the last one) on invocation as `OnNumberRolled()`.

You might have the handlers to add their results to a list or something like that, but we would need more insight on your use cases to design a satisfactory solution.

You can also iterate on handlers like this:

```
var handlers = OnNumberRolled.GetInvocationList();

foreach (var handler in handlers)
{
      // invoke and handle each handlers'result here
      Debug.Log(handler());
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I want to activate several things from one event. I thing that ```Roller.OnNumberRolled = OnRolledOne``` will overwrite other logic. Is there way to do this?

Comment: You can use `+=`. It's called delegate composition

Comment: Ish. Your delegate returns an `int`. If you create a multicast delegate using `+=`, all of the return values apart from the one from the last delegate to be called are lost

Comment: @MrWatchmanLP I added the `delegate` / `event` version, but, yeah, keep in mind canton7's comment. You may want your event handlers to add a result to some list for instance, but it could start to be spaghetti code very fast.

Comment: Thank you all, guys. That helped me a lot!

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă yep indeed, but need to use delegates and not just `System.Func`, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Pac0 `System.Func` is a delegate type

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Ha, thanks. I feel dumb now, not noticing it for so long... edited the answer again.